# SQS queue based worker node for event driven architecture

Tags: amazon-ec2, architecture, amazon-ecs, amazon-sqs, aws-fargate

I already found similar questions, but I would love to have a 2nd opinion on this. I'm working with an application that connects with multiple APIs. There I've integrator API which connects with both payment API and invoice API. Sequence and architecture diagrams are given below.

**Sequence Diagram**

[image]

**Architecture Diagram**

[image]

FYI - Both payment and invoice APIs are docker containers launched in EC2 instances in ECS cluster fronted by ALB.

Since the DBMS is a legacy system, it takes lot of time to process the data and send response back. Therefore, sometimes requests timed out due to 1 min barrier (FYI - cannot change 1 min timeout) in ALB in front of payment API. Let's assume DBMS could take even more than 15 mins as well.

Therefore, the most feasible solution I see here is to have a queue in between integrator API and payment API. But the issue is in order to process payment details through payment API, we've to send initial payment details and it could be more than 256 KB which exceeds the limit of SQS message size. For that I'm planning to use existing documentDB to stage the initial payment details and use them when payment API requests it (with queue, payment API can use meta details from SQS queue message to retrieve the correct details from database). Once the processing is over, it needs to be explicitly deleted by the payment API.

Now the other issue is how to connect with invoice API.
Before sending processed payment details response to invoice API, integrator API does some post processing. Due to event driven nature of SQS, integrator API won't receive any response. Therefore, how can I handle the invoice API now. I'm planning to move those post processing logics into payment API and invoke the invoice API once the legacy DBMS sends back the response to payment API.

FYI - Please note that user doesn't need to see the invoice details right after the invocation.

So the proposed architecture is as follows.

[image]

Can anyone let me know if there's anything I can do to improve this architecture or anything I need to change or add ?

Answer (score 2):

From what you describe, my approach would be to change the communication mechanism with the Payments API to a polling request.

The general flow would be:

[image: Payment Processing Flow]

1. Call the Payments API to process a payments request. It should respond immediately with an HTTP 202 with the id of the processing job/task.
2. Poll the Payments API to request the status/response

   a. If it's not done, it'll respond with HTTP 202 again

   b. If it's done, it'll return HTTP 200 with the resulting payment details
3. Call the Invoice API with the payment details

This means you won't have to have intermediate storage (and the synchronization issues that brings) or worry about queue message sizes, etc.